# What verbs should I know for level A2 exam?

Tags: verb, proficiency-test

Is there any page, list or link, etc. where there are all the German verbs for the A2/A1 exam?

Update : I asked the question for the Goethe Institut.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Goethe Institute publishes word lists for the different language levels, e.g. the [GOETHE-ZERTIFIKAT A2 WORTLISTE](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/en/Goethe-Zertifikat_A2_Wortliste.pdf):

[image]

Unfortunately, it's not only verbs, but all vocabulary.

Answer (score 3):

You can find lists of words (in general, not only verbs) in some of the textbooks that are available for learning German at level A1/A2 by various publishing houses.

However, as these are not standardized down to the level of single words, these lists are valid especially for these textbooks or course programmes, and perhaps in other textbooks there might be minor difference (some words missing, others in use).

Please understand that the pedagogical concept behind such courses and textbooks is not the learn by heart a certain set of words. Rather, the idea is to lead learners into using the language (pro-) actively, and **develop their competences**. Competence means here: the ability to cope with **unexpected situations** and **unfamiliar environments** by using the tools (knowledge, skills) one actually has in a creative way.

In other words: you should not be concerned with word lists. You should be concerned with reading texts and understanding them, listening to people speaking, and understanding them; practicing speaking with people; practicing writing texts that are adequate in certain situations of everyday life.

What I would do is not learning words from a word list, but: reading the texts in the book; and if I see a word I do not understand, look it up. Then read the text again. And tomorrow again. Thus you will learn the word, but in context.

If you want to look up word lists anyway, please refer to the respective textbooks.

Here is one (of dozens):

> Daniela Niebisch et al.: Schritte plus 1. Kursbuch und Arbeitsbuch. Niveau A1/1. Hueber, München 2009 (and following).

A word list is on pages 174-180. [I happen to have the 2016/10 edition]

There are various online offers with teaching materials for free. 
One is "Ich will Deutsch lernen" by the Association of German Community Colleges (Deutscher Volkshochschulverband).

Older plattform (content is good, graphics a bit outdated):

> www.iwdl.de

New plattform, opened in late 2018 (modern graphics, as for 2019 standards):

> https://deutsch.vhs-lernportal.de/

Answer (score 3):

It is the [Common European Framework of Reference for Languages](https://www.coe.int/en/web/common-european-framework-reference-languages) which defines and describes what it means to have *A2* level competence in any language. However, the framework does not list vocabulary (in any language) but instead describes the broad language skills that are required for the level, including vocabulary, grammar, understanding of context, listening skills, reading skills, speaking skills and writing skills, etc.

As a consequence, the specific vocabulary list produced by language-teaching and language-testing organizations will vary somewhat from one organization to another. It is therefore desirable to consider ***where*** you want be tested and to look at the specific test demands of the testing centre.

To learn what the testing requirements are, rather than simply find an [A2 wordlist](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/en/Goethe-Zertifikat_A2_Wortliste.pdf), you must read a document such as the [Goethe Zertifikat A2 Fit in Deutsch 2 Prüfungsziele Testbeschreibung](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/tr/Pruefungsziele_Testbeschreibung_A2_Fit2.pdf). If you do that, you will save yourself a lot of heartache.

When you consider how words function in a sentence, you will immediately recognize that in order to use the verb *beginnen*, for example, it is not sufficient to know the infinitive form. Nor is it sufficient to understand that *beginnen* corresponds in most usages to the English verb *to begin*. You must also know how to use the word in its correct grammatical form in a sentence. But just how much do you need to know for your A2 exam? That is the critical question faced by an examinee. The answer is given in the Grammatik setion of the [Testbeschreibung](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/tr/Pruefungsziele_Testbeschreibung_A2_Fit2.pdf)

```
Verb
Tempus Präsens aller Verben der Wortliste

       Perfekt aller Verben der Wortliste

       Präteritum der Verben
       haben         Wir hatten keine Lust.
       sein          Wo warst du gestern?
       kommen        Er kam zu spät.
       sagen         Dann sagte sie: …
Modalverben          Ich konnte gestern nicht kommen.

Modus  Indikativ aller Verben der Wortliste
       Konjunktiv II der Verben
       mögen         Möchtest du eine Tasse Tee?
       haben         Ich hätte gern ein Glas Cola.
       können        Könntest du mir bitte helfen?

       Imperativ
       du- und ihr-Form   Geh bitte nach Hause!
                          Kommt bitte mit!

Modalverben
       Präsens von
       können      Kannst du Gitarre spielen?
       wollen      Er will Biologie studieren.
       müssen      Ihr müsst die Hausaufgaben machen.
       möchten     Ich möchte mitkommen.
       dürfen      Darf ich das mal sehen?
       sollen      Was soll ich machen?



Verben mit trennbarem Präfix
                   Kommst du mit?
                   Wann fängt der Film an?
                   Ich muss noch einkaufen.
                   Mach bitte das Fenster zu!
```

So at *A2* level, you must, for example, be familiar with the infinitive form of all the verbs in the [word list](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/en/Goethe-Zertifikat_A2_Wortliste.pdf) and with their present indicative and perfect conjugations, but you do not have to know how to use the Präteritum (simple past) of most of the verbs!

In addition to the documents for Niveau A2 that I've already mentioned, I found the following for A1:

> A1: [Word list](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/de/A1_SD1_Wortliste_02.pdf) / [test requirements](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/en/Pruefungsziele_Testbeschreibung_A1_Fit1.pdf)

One final thing worth noting. The word lists and test requirements change slightly over the years, so you should obtain the very latest documents from your intended testing centre. The links I have included are to the most recent documents *I could find*, but they might not actually be the most up-to-date!

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, there is no such list. Exams are created by German language teachers, and they know enough well, what is really needed for which level of knowledge.

As far I know, Japanese and Chinese school system has a list of their Kanjis what the students need to learn to pass it.

However, on the exam it is not a requirement to know all the verbs, there is a point limit (60% or 70%, as far I can remember) what you need to pass.

Find exams on the net. If you can fill them, here is the time to get also the paper. If not, search for questions about effective learning tips & tricks.

Comment: As another answer points out, there **is** a list (not only verbs)