# Looking for German A1/A2 vocabulary PDF with articles

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, vocabulary, dictionary

I have looked at some vocabularies on the internet. Most of them are without articles (der, die, das) which is so important. I have found one paper with articles but it is in alphabetic order, I need mixed words. So If you have any PDF resources please share with the community.

Comment: What do you mean by mixed words?

Comment: With basic scripting knowledge you could scramble an ordered list

Comment: @infinitezero which tools can you recommend? I will look at it

Comment: This website does the job: https://onlinerandomtools.com/shuffle-lines

Comment: All vocabularies  have (der, die, das), but it is {m}->der; {f}->die or neuter->das, masculine->der

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Goethe Institut has vocabulary lists for [Niveau A1](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/de/A1_SD1_Wortliste_02.pdf), [Niveau A2](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/en/Goethe-Zertifikat_A2_Wortliste.pdf) and [Niveau B1](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/de/Goethe-Zertifikat_B1_Wortliste.pdf) in PDF format. The B1 list includes the articles and plurals for ***all*** the nouns. In contrast, the A1 and A2 lists do not include the plurals for those nouns for which it is considered unnecessary to know the plurals at A1 or A2 level.

You can find a more detailed explanation for why the lists do or don't include various bits of information in the [Goethe Zertifikat A2 Fit in Deutsch 2 Prüfungsziele Testbeschreibung](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/tr/Pruefungsziele_Testbeschreibung_A2_Fit2.pdf).

It is not clear what you mean when you say that you need "mixed words". From the preceding sentence ("I have found one paper with articles but it is in alphabetic order") you imply that you want a list that is not in alphabetical order but it is not clear. Perhaps you are *actually saying* that the problem with the list you do not like is that it groups all the nouns into gender-classes before sorting them alphabetically so that, for example, all the masculine words are together. In any case, there are a several things that might help you ...

First, the Goethe lists are organised so that the base-words themselves (i.e., the nouns) are in alphabetical order rather then being grouped into gender classes. In addition, there are [several](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/293204297) [shared](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1386119660) [decks](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1586166030) for [Anki](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/) that correspond to variants of the A1, A2 and B1 wordlists. With [Anki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anki_(software)) it is a trivial matter to export the lists as comma-separated or bar-separated text files. The files can then be directly sorted into any order you want, or they can be shuffled, using a spreadsheet program like [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) or [LibreOffice Calc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice_Calc). Alternatively, if you use a GNU based shell system of some sort (such as GNU Linux) then it is easy to [shuffle the lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/886312) in the text file so that they are in a random order rather than being alphabetically sorted.

If any of this is not clear, please feel free to modify your question to include the additional requests, or just make a comment.

Comment: Excellent answer. Are there lists for B2 and upper levels provided by the Goethe-Institut ?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no B2 list, the reason being that although there is a core vocabulary that all proficient speakers use, there is a considerable divergence in vocabulary as one becomes more proficient. For example, you work in the civil service and develop one vocabulary. I work as a plumber and develop another. Expression, rather than vocabulary becomes the defining distinguishing feature of the higher levels. Capacity for expression is explained in the Common European Framework. Have a look at this answer ... https://german.stackexchange.com/a/61705/38673